# Generating csv on php only set 1 field

Tags: php, csv

With this code

```
fputcsv($fp, array('TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME','DATA_TYPE','CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH','CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH','NUMERIC_PRECISION', 'DATETIME_PRECISION', 'TABLE_NUMBER', 'RELATED_TABLE'));
```

I get a csv file with one field with all the array content ,how I can make a field for each array element?

Comment: I find the question unclear...

Comment: `fputcsv` puts single CSV row to file.

Comment: If you' opening this file in MS Excel to check it, be aware that MS Excel uses locale-specific separators.... it isn't always a `,`, but could be a `;` depending on the locale settings of your MS Excel.

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using ms excel

Comment: Then try setting the separator argument for `fputcsv()` to a `;`; or adding a `sep=,` as the first line of the file

Comment: @MarkBaker it worked ,thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I understand u correctly, just try it this way:

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```